# Angular directive that wraps svg elements in a g group

Tags: angularjs, svg, angularjs-directive

I've been trying various iterations of declaring directives to wrap some SVG elements to no avail.  I'd like to create a set of directives that look like this:

```
<polar-graph id="G1">
    <track id="T1">
        <marker id="M1"></marker>
    </track>
    <track id="T2">
        <marker id="M2"></marker>
    </track>
</polar-graph>
```

And should be rendered like this:

```
<svg id="G1>
    <g>
        <circle id="T1"></circle>
        <path id="M1"></path>
    </g>
    <g>
        <circle id="T2"></circle>
        <path id="M2"></path>
    </g>
</svg>
```

With the new `type` property in Angular 1.3 beta, I can indicate SVG elements (yay!), however, my problem is the `g` element. Here are my templates:

```
.directive('polarGraph', function(){
    return {
        restrict : 'AE',
        type : 'svg',
        transclude : true,
        replace : true,
        template : '<svg ng-transclude></svg>'
        ...
    }
 })

.directive('track', function(){
    return {
        restrict : 'AE',
        type : 'svg',
        transclude : true,
        replace : true,
        template : '<g><circle></circle></g>'   //Not sure how to include transcluded content after the circle 
        ...
    }
 })

.directive('marker', function(){
    return {
        restrict : 'AE',
        type : 'svg',
        replace : true,
        template : '<path></path>'
        ...
    }
 })
```

When I declare my directive, I would like all of the properties of the `track` directive to map to the `circle` of the SVG and not the containing `g` group.  As it stands, Angular automatically sets the `id` and all other attributes on the `g` group.  How can I properly do this in Angular?

Comment: This feels a bit dirty, but maybe `element[0].removeAttribute('id')` in the link-function would get rid of it?

Comment: Admittedly, this works, but I'm hoping there's a cleaner solution.  Otherwise, I need to selectively determine which attributes to remove (id, class, style) and which ones to keep to make sure Angular still works (ng-scope, ng-repeat, etc)

Comment: I don't think there is a cleaner solution, but I've been wrong before.